# Dell D620 laptop has video issues that I can not diagnose

Tags: laptop, video, lcd

I took a short video of the video problems I am having, you can see it here -> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=43eNQy8oDt4

- I tested the laptop in the BIOS menu, Ubuntu and XP safe mode and the problem was still there
- Tried different resolutions and colors with no effect on the problem
- I hooked up an external monitor and the video was fine.
- Thought the problem might be in the connection to the monitor so I got replacement LCD and the problem is still there.
- The problem seems to be consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe bad ribbon pins on the graphics card or a faulty GPU? When you replaced the LCD, did you also replace the breakout board?

Comment: The only thing I replaced was the LCD itself. It's still using the same inverter as well.

Comment: In my opinion, the motherboard seems fine if external monitors are working. You may want to investigate into the breakout board and may want to buy a new housing for your LCD. Also in my opinion, it would be a good time to purchase a new laptop or have it replaced.